# How to load the data stored in a JSON file into an array or an hash table in power shell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I wanted to load the data in a JSON file into an array. The data in the JSON file is an array of arrays. After loading, the array shouldn't have extra characters like \r, \n.

How do I do it?
Below is the content of the file. I want it to be loaded as an array and not as a string.

```
[
{
    "CRLDps":  [
                   "http://crl.pki.goog/GTSGIAG3.crl"
               ],
    "aliasName":  "Google Internet Authority G3",
    "commonName":  "Google Internet Authority G3"
},
{
    "CRLDps":  [
                   "http://crl.globalsign.com/gs/gsorganizationvalsha2g2.crl"
               ],
    "aliasName":  "GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2",
    "commonName":  "GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2"
}
]
```

Comment: `Get-Content input.json | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json`? For further help please provide samles for input and desired output.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have posted the contents of the JSON file. I want to load it as an array and not as a string

Comment: @SushruthN If you pipe it to ConverFrom-Json it returns you a `PSObject`, which is more of a combination of arrays than a string..

Comment: The code in my comment will import that JSON as an array of custom objects. Does something not work?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers. It works. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a JSON file with a JSON array in it all you need to do is read that file into a single string and pass that into `ConvertFrom-Json`. That will produce an array of custom objects in PowerShell.

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.json' | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

In PowerShell v3 or newer you can substitute the `Out-String` step by adding the parameter `-Raw` to `Get-Content`:

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell v6 it's built-in with [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6) to store as hash-table:

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\input.json' | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable
```